# Screenshot with Selenium Webdriver and PHPUnit

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I know that screenshots could be taken by extending `PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase` but right now, I'm using Facebook's [php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) so I'm just extending with `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`

Is there anyway to take screenshots with this just the driver and **not extending** the extension?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$driver->takeScreenshot('/path/to/image.png');
```

Comment: takeScreenshot() also returns the image data. Try `$image = $driver->takeScreenshot();` if you want to use the image immediately instead of storing it on the disk.

Comment: Its working fine for open page but its not work popup page

Answer (score 5):

I found such solution to make screenshot on failure:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function tearDown()
{
    $status = $this->getStatus();
    if ($status == \PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner::STATUS_ERROR 
        || $status == \PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner::STATUS_FAILURE) {
        $now = new \DateTime('now');
        $screenshotFileName = $this->getParameter('screenshots_directory_full_path');
        $screenshotFileName = $screenshotFileName . $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' test ' . $this->getName() . '.png';

        $this->webDriver->takeScreenshot($screenshotFileName);
    }
    $this->webDriver->quit();
}
```

You asked this long time ago, but hope it'll help somebody else :)

Answer (score 0):

building off of what @a_sarana said. in at least versions >= 5 you can use phpunit method:

```
$this->hasFailed();
```

example

```
if($this->hasFailed())
{
    $selenium->takeScreenshot($filename);   
}
```

This assumes that you don't care the type of failure that occurred.

Side note if you end up with blank screenshots you may need to wait for the page to load. I lost about a half a days worth of work debugging that.

example

```
sleep(1); // one second
```

or

```
// wait max of 2 sec check every 1/10 sec until element is viable
$driver->wait(2, 1000)->until(
    WebDriverExpectedCondition::visibilityOfElementLocated(WebDriverBy::id("elementID")) 
);
```